# setup the guest network in KVM to interact with the outside world (google.com )

Tags: networking

I am trying to better understand the network setup in my machine.

**Host Machine Setup**

1. I have a wireless interface (**wlan0**) on my host machine which has
   the IP address as `192.168.1.9`.
2. The default gateway of this host is the router which goes to the
   outside world through my ISP, whose IP address is `192.168.1.1`.
3. The route -n command in my host machine returns me the output as,

   ```
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
   169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
   192.168.1.160   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 virbr2
   ```

**Guest Machine Setup**

Now, I setup a guest OS in KVM as below.

1. The KVM is in a sub-network which has the details as
   `192.168.1.160/27`.
2. The DHCP start is `192.168.1.176` and the DHCP end is `192.168.1.190`.
3. I also did the below command for my KVM configuration to work.

   ```
   arp -i wlan0 -Ds 192.168.1.9 wlan0 pub
   ```

From the guest OS, I see that my IP address is `192.168.1.179`. My `route -n` command in the guest machine returns me the output as,

```
kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask
0.0.0.0        192.168.1.161    0.0.0.0
192.168.1.160  0.0.0.0          255.255.255.224
```

How can I make the guest OS to interact with the outside world?

**EDIT**

This is the output of `virsh net-list --all`.

```
ramesh@ramesh-pc:~$ virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 arpbr0               inactive   yes           yes
 default              active     yes           yes
 proxyArp             active     yes           yes
```

Comment: Can you check your setup w/ virsh as described here: http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#NAT_forwarding_.28aka_.22virtual_networks.22.29. Also the box needs to allow this: `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
`.

Comment: @slm, thanks. I have added the output to the question.

Comment: What's the status of ipv4.ip_forward?

Comment: Also if you take a look at your setup using virt-manager: http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/02/kvm-virtualization-network-nat-configuration-in-kvm-hypervisor.html

Comment: I modified the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file to change the status of ipv4.ip_forward to 1.

Comment: No diff with that?

Comment: @slm, unfortunately no. I was not able to ping to my host or host gateway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to thank [user slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) for guiding me in the right direction in setting up the guest network in the *KVM*. I will add the screen shots to the answer so that it will be more informative.

I assume the `virt-manager` package is installed and also the host machine is setup with the necessary packages for *KVM* to work.

---

### Preparing the Network For Guest to Host Interaction

---

The main step in the *KVM* is setting up of the network. If the machine is not available in the network, then it serves no purpose, *be it physical or virtual*.

Type `virt-manager` in the terminal. The console would show up as
    below.

[image: Initial Virtual Manager Console Window]

Click on **Edit -> Connection Details** and a new screen would pop
    up as below.

[image: After Clicking Edit button]

Click on **Virtual Networks** tab and from there click on the **+**
    button to add a new network to the *KVM* guests.

[image: Creating a new Virtual Network]

Click on **Forward** and then we would be presented with the below
    screen. Now, the IPV4 addresses we choose here is completely up to
    our choice and we could optimize this step to suit our actual needs.

[image: Choosing an IPv4 Address Space]

After we click on **Forward** in the above screen, we would be presented
    with the below screen. In this step, it basically tells the address
    space available for us.

[image: DHCP Addresses available]

In this step, choose forwarding to physical network and select the
    host's  network interface which will help the guests to interact
    with the outside world.

[image: Choose NAT with the host physical device]

After the above step, we are almost done and we just would be
    presented with the below screen, which is kind of a review of all
    the details we chose so far.

[image: Final Step]

---

### Adding this new device to our Guest OS

---

From the initial screen of `virt-manager`, click on the `Open` and
    we will be presented with a screen as below.

[image: First Step]

From the above screen, click on the **i** to open up another screen as
    below.

[image: second step]

Click on **Add Hardware** and select *Network*. In the *Network* tab, select the host device as our newly created network in the previous step and click on **Finish** as shown in the below screen.

[image: Final Configuration]

---

### Testing in the guest OS

---

Now, inside the guest OS make sure that you are able to `ping` the *host* machine and outside network such as *google*. If the ping succeeds, then we have successfully setup our network in the guest OS.

---

### References

---

[The reference material used to setup the guest network](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/02/kvm-virtualization-network-nat-configuration-in-kvm-hypervisor.html)

Answer (score 0):

setup static routes in your router(192.168.1.1).

```
# ip route add 192.168.1.160/27 via 192.168.1.9 dev < wlan iface>
```

or via webui.

add `iptables` forward routes on your host from router to `192.168.1.160/27` and  vice versa (although, i think, `libvirt` provides these rules already).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this solution did not work.

Comment: is your KVM guest _NATed_ or _routed_ to your host?

Comment: The KVM is routed to the host.